# WITH Clause inside PL-SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to use 'WITH' clause inside PL-SQL block :

Cursor using WITH clause as follows :

```
  CURSOR c_API_MSG
  IS
      WITH SAMI AS (SELECT * FROM NAGENDRA WHERE STATUS = 'NEW')
      SELECT * FROM SAMI WHERE ROWNUM <= TO_NUMBER (10);
```

Execution :

```
FOR v_Rec IN c_API_MSG
  LOOP
     BEGIN
        -- My LOGIC
END;
END LOOP;
```

It is not executing properly. It is not going inside loop. seems like cursor not able to fetch rows & that's why exiting.

Normal sub-query without with clause working fine. With clause working fine on editor.

Is there any limitation of using 'WITH' clause or am I missing something here ?

**Observations :**

Inside toad editor with below query :

If I Use f9 (normal execute) : 5 rows found (Correct result)

**If I use f5 : No rows found (This is I am worried about)**

```
      WITH SAMI AS (SELECT * FROM NAGENDRA WHERE STATUS = 'NEW')
      SELECT * FROM SAMI WHERE ROWNUM <= TO_NUMBER (10);
```

Comment: Have you committed all changes done to NAGENDRA table?

Comment: as an aside: `TO_NUMBER (10)` ... you're converting a number into a number? Why bother? just use `10` instead.

Comment: Please show the *complete* and *real* code you're running. With > 99% probability, you have a flaw in your logic. Strip it down to a [MCVE], and provide the table definition and content (possibly with dummy data if you can't post the real data).

Comment: Also, according to the TOAD documentation, F9 runs a single statement, whereas F5 runs all statements. My guess would be that you execute multiple statements and the last one returns no data. But again: it's impossible to help you unless you provide more information.

Comment: Thank you all for response. @MarcinWroblewski : Yes changes were commited.

Comment: @Boneist : Actually that was varchar in real code. In hurry of creating dummy example as used it like this.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt : Thanks. Will update the question with more details / dummy data soon

Comment: Guys its working now. May be the commit issue identified by @MarcinWroblewski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Yes PLSQL supports "WITH" clause. Plz see below snippet.

```
SET sqlbl ON;
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  CURSOR LV_CUR
  IS
  WITH
    TEMP_AV AS
    (
      SELECT
        LEVEL
      FROM
        DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10
    )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TEMP_AV;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN LV_CUR
  LOOP
    NULL;
    dbms_output.put_line(i.level);
  END LOOP;
END;
```